# Optional bottom border on a div

Tags: css

I have two HTML samples... Basically there is always a name div in the info div but the total number of could be more.

1)

```
<div class="person">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="name">Isabelle  of_Bavaria</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2)

```
<div class="person">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="name">King of France Charles_V  the_Wise</div>
        <div class="title"><label>Title:</label>King of France</div>
        <div class="date"><label>Birth:</label>Jan 21st, 1337</div>
        <div class="date"><label>Death:</label>Sep 16th, 1380</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this bit of CSS to add a line under the name as well as a box around the person div.

```
.person .name
{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.person
{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Is there anything I can do with the css to prevent the name from having a border in sample 1 while leaving it in sample 2 without the need for additional classes or divs?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to have the underline in sample 2 because there are sibling divs to the name div (which you want to separate from them), while in sample 1, there are no following (sibling) divs to name, so you don't want an underline? There should be a way in CSS to do that. Consider putting a top border on title instead of a bottom border on name.

Comment: @PhilPerry - Yes, that is what I am trying to do. The issue with the top border is that I don't know what will be the next div will be, might be title, might be date, might be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this piece of CSS at the top of your *.person .name* entry

```
.person .name:only-of-type
{
    border-bottom: 0px transparent;
}
```

This piece of CSS means that if there is only *one of the element type using the .name class* in .person (in this example it's a div), it will not have a bottom border. You have to put it before the *.person .name* in order to overwrite it.

**EDIT :**

After thinking about it a bit more, i think the pseudo class *:only-child* would be better suited for your needs instead of *:only-of-type* since it will only apply if the *.name* is the only child of *.person*. So here's the updated CSS

```
.person .name:only-child
{
    border-bottom: 0px transparent;
}
```

Comment: Both seem to work quite well. Whats the browser compatibility with these two pseudo classes?

Comment: @Justin808 I am not sure but it seems that IE8 and less cant use theses pseudo classes but IE9+ and all other browser support it. Also, here's a verry cool site for browser comptability question : http://caniuse.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Something logically like this?

```
.person > .info[having more than one div child] > .name
{
    border-bottom: ...
}
```

sadly, i don't think there's a `[...]` selector quite like that, however, there are "adjacent sibling selectors" ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors )

Maybe as @PhilPerry has suggested, you could change the concept to being "put a top-border on the div immediately following the first-child (or name)", like so:

```
.name:first-child + div
{
    border-top: ...
}
```